# Remove comma from group regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible from this:

US Patent 6,570,557

retrieve 3 groups being:

1. US
2. Patent
3. 6570557 (without the commas)

So far I got:

```
(US)(\s{1}Patent\s{1})(\d{1},\d{3},\d{3})
```

and was trying `(?!,)` to get rid of the commas then I effectively get rid of the whole number.

Comment: Why not just retrieve the number with the commas, and then strip the commas when you need to? `/(US)(\sPatent\s)([\d,]*)/` Lazy ftw!

Comment: I forgot to say I can't Change the JS I was trying to achieve this in regex only

Comment: The regex is not in the JS?

Comment: well no... its retrieved through a configuration mechanism outside the js

Answer (score 10):

Try with:

```
var input   = 'US Patent 6,570,557',
    matches = input.match(/^(\w+) (\w+) ([\d,]+)/),

    code = matches[1],
    name = matches[2],
    numb = matches[3].replace(/,/g,'');
```

Comment: Djien dobry, +1 for clean and compact. I've been noticing your fine work in the regex tag lately but looks you've been working there for a long time. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regex, you can do it with 2 simple functions:

```
var str = "US Patent 6,570,557"; // Your input
var array = str.split(" "); // Separating each word
array[2] = array[2].replace(",", ""); // Removing commas
return array; // The output
```

This should be faster too.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore the commas when matching, unless you match the number as three separate parts and then join them together.

It would be much preferable to strip the delimiters from the number from the matching results with [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

Just add more groups like so:

```
(US)(\s{1}Patent\s{1})(\d{1}),(\d{3}),(\d{3})
```

And then concatenate the last 3 groups

Comment: Of course the OP isn't sure that Patent # is between `1,000,000` and `9,999,999`.